# How to change the link without refreshing the entire page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, elementor

Hi I have an webpage which is designed using Elementor plugin in wordpress. There is 4 tabs in it i have written some script for change the url when click on the tab. Now the question is when i click on the any tab it is refreshing the page i dont want to refresh the page i just needs to change the tab and change the url based on the tab

Website link : https://yourdataconnect.com/company/caterpillar-inc/

Click on the link and you can see 4 tabs 1)Data Monetization Index 2)Analysis 3)Data Products 4)Data Management Spend

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
  
   var dmi_12 = document.getElementById("elementor-tab-title-1841");
  if(window.location.search!=="?DataMonetizationIndex"){
    dmi_12.onclick = link;
    function  link(){
       window.location.search="?DataMonetizationIndex"
    }
  }
  var ans = document.getElementById("elementor-tab-title-1842");
  if(window.location.search!=="?Analysis"){
    ans.onclick = link;
    function  link(){
       window.location.search="?Analysis"
    }
  }
    var dp = document.getElementById("elementor-tab-title-1843");
  if(window.location.search!=="?DataProducts"){
    dp.onclick = link;
    function  link(){
       window.location.search="?DataProducts"
    }
           
 }
   var dme = document.getElementById("elementor-tab-title-1844");
  if(window.location.search!=="?DataManagementSpend"){
    dme.onclick = link;
    function  link(){
       window.location.search="?DataManagementSpend"
    }
  }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
setTimeout(function() {

jQuery(function($){

let desktoptitles = $('.elementor-tab-desktop-title');
let mobiletitles = $('.elementor-tab-mobile-title');

let strings = ['?DataMonetizationIndex',
'?Analysis','?DataProducts','?DataManagementSpend'
];

strings.forEach( (string,i) => {
if (window.location.href.indexOf(string) > -1) {
desktoptitles.eq(i).click();
mobiletitles.eq(i).click();
$('html, body')
} } );
}); }, 1200); });
</script>
```

Can you anyone help me on this one

Answer (score 0):

You might take a closer look at [pushState from the history-api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState). There you can simply add a new history-entry without reloading the page. For your scenario, the example with the query parameter change might be the most interesting.

```js
const url = new URL(window.location);
url.searchParams.set('foo', 'bar');
window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
```

Comment: hi @Jan thanks for answered the question can you explain the code briefly or can you update the your suggestion in the original code actually i am new to this html and javascript stuff